# Get date and month from timestamp

Tags: jquery, json, timestamp

I have got a problem with finding a solution on getting DATE and MONTH only from my json' timestamps. My json looks like:

```
{
 "status": "ok",
 "posts": [
 { 
  "id": "21",
  "title": "Title",
  "date": "1374267600"
}
]
}
```

and ajax call:

```
   $.ajax({ 
    url: ,
    async: false,
    callback: 'callback',
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    timeout: 2000,
    success: function (data, status) {


       if (data !== undefined && data.posts !== undefined) {

        $('#dates').append('<div id="date">' + item.date + '</div><div id="month">' + item.date + '</div>');
       }    
    }
});
```

It displays the stamp only. Can you help me please?

Also if you can do it on jsfiddle I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Where does `item` comes from?

Comment: sorry Pieter you are right. My mistake with having **item**, even if I fix it - it doesn't show my stamp properly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert the timestamp to a date object first.
Note that you have to multiply timestamp with 1000 because javascript date constructor takes miliseconds while timestamp is in seconds

```
months = ["jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec"];
timestamp = "1374267600";
var jsDate = new Date(timestamp*1000);

$('#dates').append('<div id="date">' + jsDate.toDateString() + '</div>'+
'<div id="month">' + months[jsDate.getMonth()] + '</div>');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgx2w/)

Comment: It is working with out multiply with 1000, when I multiply with 1000 it show after the 3days date.

Answer (score 2):

The following function will transform it into a DDMMYY format:

```
function unixEpochTime_TO_Date_DDMMYY (unixEpochTime, returnUTC) {
    var year, month, day;
    var dateObj = new Date (unixEpochTime * 1000);

    if (returnUTC) {
        year    = dateObj.getUTCFullYear ();
        month   = dateObj.getUTCMonth ();
        day     = dateObj.getUTCDate ();
    }
    else {
        year    = dateObj.getFullYear ();
        month   = dateObj.getMonth ();
        day     = dateObj.getDate ();
    }

    //-- Month starts with 0, not 1.  Compensate.
    month      += 1;

    /*-- Since we want DDMMYY, we need to trim the year and zero-pad
        the day and month.
        Note:  Use YYMMDD, for sorting that makes sense.
    */
    year    = (""  + year) .slice (-2);
    month   = ("0" + month).slice (-2);
    day     = ("0" + day)  .slice (-2);

    return day + month + year;
}
```

Utility:

```
var obj = {
     "status": "ok",
     "posts": [
         { 
              "id": "21",
              "title": "Title",
              "date": "1374267600"
         }
    ]
};

alert(unixEpochTime_TO_Date_DDMMYY(obj.posts[0].date, " Local"));
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2cjAJ/)

Comment: Thank you John. Can you help me to display date and month in seperate divs please?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function i wrote for this that will give you all the parameters you need and even more.

```
/*
 * This function get all date from timestamp
 */
function dataFromTimestamp(timestamp){
    var d = new Date(timestamp);

    // Time
    var h = addZero(d.getHours());              //hours
    var m = addZero(d.getMinutes());            //minutes
    var s = addZero(d.getSeconds());            //seconds

    // Date
    var da = d.getDate();                       //day
    var mon = d.getMonth() + 1;                 //month
    var yr = d.getFullYear();                   //year
    var dw = d.getDay();                        //day in week

    // Readable feilds
    months = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"];
    var monName = months[d.getMonth()];         //month Name
    var time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;           //full time show
    var thisDay = da + "/" + mon + "/" + yr;    //full date show

    var dateTime = {
        seconds : s,
        minutes : m,
        hours : h,
        dayInMonth : da,
        month : mon,
        year : yr,
        dayInTheWeek : dw,
        monthName : monName,
        fullTime : time,
        fullDate : thisDay
    };
    return dateTime;

    function addZero(i) {
        if (i < 10) {
            i = "0" + i;
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mkammdgz/

Answer (score 1):

`item.date` is a string, and javascripts `Date()` accepts numbers, so:

```
var ms    = parseInt(item.posts[0].date, 10) * 1000,
    date  = new Date(ms),
    day   = date.getDate(),
    month = date.getMonth() + 1,
    elem1 = $('<div />', {id : 'date',  text : day}),
    elem2 = $('<div />', {id : 'month', text : month});

$('#dates').append(elem1, elem2);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XhZLD/1/)

Answer (score 0):

That date is actually the milliseconds since January 1st, 12:00 A.M. 1970. If you use

You can convert that milliseconds string to the date object in javascript with:

```
var d = new Date(item.date);
```

Then you can use `d.toUTCString()` to get the date in UTC format.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = Date.parse(item.date);
var month = date.getMonth();
var day = date.getDay();
var year = date.getYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var dt = new Date();
  var time = dt.getMonth()+1 +""+ dt.getDate()+ "" +dt.getFullYear() +""+ dt.getHours() +""+ dt.getMinutes() +""+ dt.getSeconds();

  console.log(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late but i faced this problem and i found a solution for it.

Try instead using  `moment()` to convert from Timestamp into actual Date

To get full date, use `moment(Timestamp).format('MM/DD/YYYY')`

To get month name, use `moment(Timestamp).format('MMMM')`

in case of your code, try the following:

```js
$('#dates').append('<div id="date">' + 
  moment(item.date).format('MM/DD/YYYY') + 
  '</div><div id="month">' + 
  moment(item.date).format('MMMM') + 
  '</div>');
```